# Safe to do firmware updates for multiple items at same time using SUU on Dell server?

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell, firmware, dell-openmanage

I've run SUU on an older production server that I recently became responsible for (PowerEdge R730) and it has many different firmware updates listed. Is it save to just click the upgrade button or should they be done individually?

The youtube videos I've found show people just clicking the upgrade button and it all being done but I wanted to reach out to community to see if it is really that simple before I do it. My main concern are the disk and raid controller firmware's. Will the raid array be maintained if I update all the disk firmware's and raid controller firmware at the same time?

Results of SUU are shown below:

[image: SUU results]

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's safe to perform all of the updates at once. The SUU will manage the installation of all updates. It will list which updates require a reboot after they have been installed.

Yes, your RAID array will be maintained.